# How to set label to secondary IP address with netplan

Tags: networking, netplan

Until Ubuntu 16.04, I've set label (eg: `eth0:1`) to secondary IP address with the following `/etc/network/interfaces`.

```
# primary address
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address  192.0.2.100
  netmask  255.255.255.0
  gateway  192.0.2.1

# secodary address with label "eth0:1"
auto  eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
  address 192.0.2.20
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

How can I set lable (eg: `eth0:1`) with Ubuntu 18.04 and netplan?

I read https://netplan.io/reference but cannot find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netplan does not support interface aliases (what you are calling here a "label").  The convention is to assign multiple addresses to the interface instead.

Answer (score 2):

Netplan support the `label` option for networkd backend only: https://netplan.io/reference/#common-properties-for-physical-device-types

Comment: Notable that while the "label" feature is clearly documented. It appears to do nothing on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS. No error (it parses); but no change to the files generated in /run/systemd/network/*. (netplan version: 0.106.1-7ubuntu0.22.04.2 )